# git - Commit and push folder then stop tracking

Tags: git, github

I need to push a dummy file in a folder to my repo so it will sit there unchanged and serve as an example. The file is located inside a sub-folder like so:

```
/main-repo/main-code.py
/main-repo/.gitignore
/main-repo/sub-folder/dummy-file.dat
```

I can commit and push these files and folders without issues. What I need to do after that is tell `git` to *stop* tracking the `sub-folder` folder and all its contents while *at the same time* keeping it in the repo (I use `Github`)

I tried adding `sub-folder/*` to `.gitignore` but the changes were still being tracked. So I tried removing the file from cache with:

```
git rm --cached sub-folder/dummy-file.dat
```

but this also removed the file from the repo after I pushed.

So to recap: I want to do a first push of `sub-folder/dummy-file.dat` and after that stop tracking all changes to *any* file inside that subfolder *while* keeping the initial state of the subfolder in my repo.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your motivation for doing this? That might help us to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Chris as I said, I need to create a dummy version for the file to serve as an example. Said file holds input parameters for the main code. After pushing the example version of that file, I keep working and thus modifying it, but I don't want those modifications to be tracked since they only correspond to _my_ workflow with the code.

Comment: It wasn't clear what the purpose of the dummy file was. Now that you've said "After pushing the example version of that file, I keep working and thus modifying it, but I don't want those modifications to be tracked since they only correspond to *my* workflow with the code" it is more clear. hammar's answer below is what I would recommend as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `assume-unchanged` flag of `update-index` - this will allow any local changes to a tracked file be ignored by git.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

From the `git-update-index` man page

> When these flags are specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated. Instead, these options set and unset the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths. When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, Git stops checking the working tree files for possible modifications, so you need to manually unset the bit to tell Git when you change the working tree file.

To undo the effect of above, use:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

So, after the initial push, use --assume-unchanged on each of the files, and GIT will never consider those files to be change, or include them in add or commit operations.

Comment: This looks very good, does it also work on folders? Say for example if I want to not-track modifications done to files inside a folder after the initial push (whether it is creating/deleting/editing files)?

Comment: Git doesn't track directories, only the files in them.  You can apply this to all files in a directory. One easy way to do this is with "find mydir -type f | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged"

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to this one, the other is a work-around but this is the actual answer to the question made. Thanks Dave! (and sorry for the late response)

Answer (score 2):

The files tracked by Git are precisely the files in the last commit on the branch, so you cannot stop tracking a file without removing it from the branch.

I suggest solving your problem in a different way.

On a project I work on, we had a similar problem when we wanted to have an example configuration file in the repo, but at the same time allow for local modifications. The way we solved it was to commit the file with an `.example` extension to the repo, and add the old file name to `.gitignore`. Then, if you want the example configuration, you can just symlink to it.

Comment: Too bad it can't be done, but this seems like a reasonable work-around. Thanks!